# Not receiving the correct Output in C#

Tags: c#, loops

So I am doing a homework assignment and for some reason my variable is not giving me the correct output. Using 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 as the judge scores and 1.2 as the degree of difficulty, I should receive 9.6 back for the final dive score.. but for some reason I am receiving 8.. Any ideas?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Rickerson_Bret_iLab3
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string wouldContinue;

        do
        {

            string diverName;
            string diverCity;
            double degreeofDiff = 0;
            double scoreJudge = 0;
            bool validDegree = false;
            double totalJudgeScore = 0;
            int i = 1;
            double highJudgeScore = 0;
            double lowJudgeScore = 0;

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the diver's name...");
            diverName = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the diver's city...");
            diverCity = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());

            while (validDegree == false)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the degree of difficulty for this dive...");
                degreeofDiff = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

                if (degreeofDiff < 1.00 || degreeofDiff > 1.67)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Re-enter a valid degree of difficulty (Valid Range: 1.00 - 1.67");
                    validDegree = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    validDegree = true;
                }
            }

            while (i < 6)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the judge #" + i + " score...");
                scoreJudge = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

                if (scoreJudge > 10 || scoreJudge < 1)
                {
                    bool validScore = false;

                    while (validScore == false)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Enter a valid Judge Score for judge #" + i + "...");
                        scoreJudge = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

                        if (scoreJudge > 10 || scoreJudge < 1)
                        {
                            validScore = false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            validScore = true;
                        }
                    }

                }

                if (scoreJudge > highJudgeScore)
                {
                    highJudgeScore = scoreJudge;
                    Console.WriteLine(highJudgeScore);
                }

                if (scoreJudge < lowJudgeScore)
                {
                    lowJudgeScore = scoreJudge;
                    Console.WriteLine(lowJudgeScore);
                }

                i++;
                totalJudgeScore = totalJudgeScore + scoreJudge;
                Console.WriteLine(totalJudgeScore);
                Console.WriteLine(scoreJudge);
            }

            double highLow = highJudgeScore + lowJudgeScore;
            totalJudgeScore = totalJudgeScore - highLow;
            totalJudgeScore = (totalJudgeScore / 3) * degreeofDiff;

            Console.WriteLine("Diver: " + diverName);
            Console.WriteLine("Diver City: " + diverCity);
            Console.WriteLine("Dive Degree of Difficulty: " + degreeofDiff);
            Console.WriteLine("Dive Score: " + totalJudgeScore);

            Console.WriteLine("Would you like to enter another diver? Enter y for yes or n for no...");
            wouldContinue = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
            wouldContinue.ToUpper();




        } while (wouldContinue == "Y");
    }
}
```

}

I want to add. I attempted to verify that it was accepting the data correctly by having it display the variables as it went through or anytime the variable was manipulated...it appears to be correct throughout but at the end is when I have the issue with variable "totalJudgeScore"

Edit2: I have since found that for some reason the code is not following the last 2 if statements properly. It is storing "scoreJudge" to "highJudgeScore" and "lowJudgeScore" each time and overwriting the data incorrectly.

Comment: Absolutely no ideas, I reproduced the steps you mentioned with exactly the same input you provided and I'm getting a score of 12...so I have no idea how you can get 8 at all

Comment: @Leo it should be giving 9.6 as to you as well. Ideally anyways. The math at the bottom of the code should add the low and high judge scores and subtract them from the total. Then divide the total score by 3 and then finally multiply by the degree of difficulty

Comment: highJudgeScore and lowJudgeScore is always 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is that the `lowJudgeScore` is never set during the loop. Add this `else` block and to initialize the `lowJudgeScore`...

```
                if (scoreJudge < lowJudgeScore)
                {
                    lowJudgeScore = scoreJudge;
                    Console.WriteLine(lowJudgeScore);
                }
                //Add this else block to initialize the low score variable
                else if (lowJudgeScore == 0)
                {
                    lowJudgeScore = scoreJudge;
                }
```

Comment: That did it...wow...any idea why it wasn't initializing that variable? I even set it to a higher number (20) per LVBen's suggestion and still was not getting the correct output.

Answer (score 2):

Your lowJudgeScore is never getting set after it gets set to 0.  You should have it default to 10 or higher, so that it gets set correctly.

Try this:

```
double lowJudgeScore = 10.0;
```

Comment: I did that (set lowJudgeScore to 20) and I'm still receiving the same issue. It is setting lowJudgeScore and highJudgeScore to the number entered for "judgeScore" each time. Its executing as if the math is not executing properly and the if statements are being ignored.

Comment: Really?  I took your code exactly and changed the 0 to 10.0 and now my result is 9.6.  I used to be a diver, so I like this question.  :-)

Comment: I'm not calling you a liar, I swear. But here is a screenshot of the console window http://i.imgur.com/q3Krp2V.jpg and here is a screenshot(s) of the code http://i.imgur.com/taqy9FB.jpg http://i.imgur.com/WQgZhvO.jpg  http://i.imgur.com/mNLsHp4.jpg

Comment: Where are those two extra "20"s coming from?  Between Jude #5 score and Diver:, I have only 4 numbers.  Why do you have 6?  Is your code different than what you posted?  Copy the code from your question and replace everything you have.  Then, change the 0 to 10.0.

Comment: I altered it for a moment to see what it was setting the highLow variable to and the totalJudgeScore after the math started. It was correct and I forgot to remove it before the screenshots.